# Is it possible to use a type alias in a GADT definition?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I've been playing around defining a GADT for WebAssembly instructions. Many of these instruction constructors have identical signatures:

```
data Instruction result where
    Add :: Instruction r -> Instruction r -> Instruction r
    Sub :: Instruction r -> Instruction r -> Instruction r
    Mul :: Instruction r -> Instruction r -> Instruction r
```

With normal values, you could simply declare a type alias for these binary operators:

```
type Binop r = Instruction r -> Instruction r -> Instruction r
```

However, when I use the alias in the GADT definition:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

module Data.Instruction where

type Binop r = Instruction r -> Instruction r -> Instruction r

data Instruction result where
    Add :: Binop r
    Sub :: Binop r
    Mul :: Binop r
```

It fails to compile:

```
[6 of 6] Compiling Data.Instruction ( src/Data/Instruction.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/Data/Instruction.o )

.../src/Data/Instruction.hs:8:5: error:
    • Data constructor ‘Add’ returns type ‘Binop r’
        instead of an instance of its parent type ‘Instruction result’
    • In the definition of data constructor ‘Add’
      In the data type declaration for ‘Instruction’
   |
11 |     Add :: Binop r
   |     ^
```

Is there any way to achieve this with GHC? If not, what is the cause of the limitation?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @Justin L. I've updated the question

Comment: You could of course play the usual trick of `data BinOp = Add | Sub | mul` and `data Instruction r where BinOp :: BinOp -> Instruction r -> Instruction r -> Instruction r`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It **is** possible, but not in the way you've done it. This here does work:

```
type Foo = Bar Int

data Bar a where
  Bar :: Foo
```

...because `Foo` does in fact have the form `Bar a`, with `a ~ Int`. However, this doesn't:

```
type Foo = Int -> Bar Int

data Bar a where
  Bar :: Foo
```

And it can't work, because the GADT constructor

```
data Bar a where
  Bar :: Int -> Bar Int
```

does not actually declare an “invertible function” `Bar :: Int -> Bar Int`. Rather, it declares something like the following:

```
data Bar' a = Bar' (a :~: Int) Int
```

i.e., it encapsulates a (runtime-readable) proof that the `a` parameter type is in fact `Int`. The GADT syntax hides this under the hood, but it means you can't just substitute `Int -> Bar Int` with a type synonym there, because that type synonym would *not* know how to encapsulate this type-equality proof.

...thinking about it, I'm not sure why my first example actually works, since it would seem to run into the same issue...

Comment: That is ... weird. Your surprisingly-working example actually does seem to produce a constructor of the right type. It would be awfully nice if the OP's example would work too; it really doesn't seem like it should be so hard.

Comment: This is helpful, but does this mean the GADT definition signatures are just sugar for more complicated types? If so, where can I read about this?

Comment: I don't know how GHC actually does GADTs, but they certainly can be understood as wrappers around reified constraints (ofte, equality constraints). [Here's a blog post](https://medium.com/@jonathangfischoff/existential-quantification-patterns-and-antipatterns-3b7b683b7d71) that discusses this quite a bit.